# Free ASP.Net controls for non-profits / charities

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-controls

I am doing a website for a charity outside of work. I can't use the normal control libraries I would use at work because of the licencing (they won't let me), and predictably the charity can't afford them for a one-off project.
I am particularly struggling for a good grid control and a hierarchy diagram control.

Do any of the vendors give free licences to these kind of projects?
Or are there other good options?

Comment: I would contact the different vendors directly and ask - they may be more amenable if you offer to promote them on the site (footer link - "powered by", logos, etc...)

Comment: ComponentArt offers a discount (~25% I recall correctly) for non-profit projects

Answer (score 2):

Why is customising the built-in .NET ones out of the question? Does your client have some special requirements?

Few things to check out:

- https://www.devexpress.com/Products/Free/NetOffer/
- http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com
- http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=web%20controls&sortBy=Relevance&licenses=|&ac=8
- http://ideasparks.codeplex.com/

Happy hunting!

Comment: I wasn't trying to get into the "3rd party Vs hand-crafted" argument. At work I use Telerik, and think I can produce better & faster with fewer lines of code for others to maintain because of it.   The grid requirements are for popup menus, right clicking etc etc.  All stuff I can do with the ajax toolkit, but it would be a lot easier with a commercial component.

Comment: Yes of course, rich-web controls ;-)

More often than not, when people want something extra to what's provided by MS controls its usually AJaX that they're after. It is getting easier (.Net v4) to do this stuff manually now, but yes, sometimes, for quick and dirty stuff, off-the-shelf is the most pragmatic option. I asked the question because it wasn't apparent whether your client had special additional requiremnts e.g. accessibility for hearing/vision impaired users etc.

Comment: No, no special requirements.  Just quite a lot of editing data in a grid and displaying family trees (which I can't find a free control for).

Comment: Family tree component - hmm I suspect that'll be tricky to find FOC. I would suggest you knock up an XML format (perhaps base it on GEDCOM) and try binding to it in different ways - maybe hack the TreeView.